# Memory exhausted errors on a fresh install when trying to debug objects generated by cake core

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

```
Error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 118015334 bytes) 
File: /var/www/composer.cakePHP/Vendor/pear-pear.cakephp.org/CakePHP/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php  
Line: 611
```

Fresh install of CakePHP 2.4.3 and I can't debug $this or $this->Form or anything of that nature.  I have another install of cake 2.1 and debugging these variables works just fine.  I can debug basic vars in the application but if i want to look at instantiated cake object.. no go.

here's my AppController config:

```
    class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array(
            'Acl',
            'Session',
            'Auth' => array(
                    'authorize' => array(
                            'Actions' => array('actionPath' =>     'controllers')
                    )
            ),
            'DebugKit.Toolbar'
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' =>     'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'adminHomes', 'action' =>     'index');

        //$this->Auth->allow('display');
        //$this->Auth->allow();
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase the memory until you are able to see what the variables contain eq: `ini_set('memory_limit','512M');`

However, $this, $this->Form are quite big objects and you shouldn't have to debug them.

Have you tried [the Debugger class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#debugger-class)  ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the object chains can contain cyclic references and trying to print them would cause infinite loop. There's no real solution for this expect not trying to debug such object instances. Also as @cornelb pointed out trying to debug `$this` or `$this->Form` would output so much info it would be very difficult to pin point useful debugging info.